# Can I use both Rspec and Minitest Rails for testing my Rails app at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

Just like what the title says. I have an application where 99% of all my code is tested by rails-minitest. However, I tehe 1% code that is being tested by rspec is a rake task that I want to implement. I chose rspec because there was a lot more support, how to's, blogs, and resources for testing rake tasks with rspec as opposed to minitest-rails.

Right now I can run rspec to test my task but minitest can't be run anymore.

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `setup' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationController::TestController:Class
```

Is there a way I can do both?

--------Update------

The commands are basic `rake test` and `rspec spec`

Comment: How are you running your tests? MiniTest usually runs against the `/test` directory and RSpec usually likes the `/spec` directory. Can you show us what command you are running?

Comment: Thanks for the reply engineersmnky, I run `rake test` and then `rspec spec`